# SQL Server query passing list of parameters containing numeric and character id's

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL 2008
I need help with a query. I was working fine before but, now i am getting arguments that overlap rendering this query useless.
Basically, i am passing a list of parameters in the format

'1_s, 22_o, 1_u, 35_t'... 
where first token is numeric id and second it the type of the product

Previously, i separated numeric id's from the product types and it was fine because the ids were far apart and there was no overlap. but, now due to system being replaced and ids were restarted i am getting products from different types with the same id as you can see 1_s and 1_u.

How can i separate them?

This is the list of arguments passed as a string:
34_o,31_s,32_o,20_t,18_u,17_u,33_o,38_o,34_s,36_o,22_t,20_u,19_u,37_o,42_o,37_s,40_o,24_t,22_u,21_u,41_o

The the query is below:

```
SELECT COUNT(bs.product_id) as num_of_products, jb.join_id, jb.join_name, jb.join_name_fr, 
        SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.ee_premium,0),2) + Round(ISNULL(ebs.employer_premium,0),2)) AS premium,
        SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.ee_premium,0),2)) AS ee_premium,
        SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.er_premium,0),2)) AS er_premium,
        SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.ee_tax_prov,0),2) + Round(ISNULL(ebs.er_tax_prov,0),2)) AS sales_tax,
        SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.ee_tax_fed,0),2) + Round(ISNULL(ebs.er_tax_fed,0),2)) AS fed_tax,
        SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.ee_tax_hst,0),2) + Round(ISNULL(ebs.er_tax_hst,0),2)) AS hst_tax,
        jb.order_id,
    CASE 
            WHEN bsb.product_type = 't' OR bsb.product_type = 'u' OR bsb.product_type = 'o'
                THEN SUM(volume) 
            ELSE 0
        END
        AS volume_billed,
        CASE 
    WHEN bsb.product_type = 's' 
                THEN ebs.product_category 
            ELSE ''
        END
        FROM BillStatement ebs
        INNER JOIN tblEmpInfo bei ON bei.billstatementvalue_id = ebs.billstatementvalue_id
        INNER JOIN tblStatementProduct bsb ON bsb.statementproduct_id = ebs.statementproduct_id
        INNER JOIN tblStatement bs ON bs.statement_id = bsb.statement_id
        INNER JOIN JoinedPlanPoducts jb ON jb.product_id = bsb.product_id AND jb.product_type = bsb.product_type
        WHERE 

bsb.product_id IN ((select * from dbo.StringToTable('34,31,32,20,18,17,33,38,34,36,22,20,19,37,42,37,40,24,22,21,41',',')))
    AND bsb.product_type IN ('o','s','t','u')


    GROUP BY jb.join_id, jb.join_name, jb.join_name_fr, jb.order_id, bsb.product_type, ebs.product_category
```

I need the list of arguments look something like that:

```
AND 
        (
        (bsb.product_id IN ((select * from dbo.StringToTable('31,34,37',','))) AND bsb.product_type = 's')
        OR
        (bsb.product_id IN ((select * from dbo.StringToTable('20,22,24',','))) AND bsb.product_type = 't')
        OR
        (bsb.product_id IN ((select * from dbo.StringToTable('17,18,19,20,21',','))) AND bsb.product_type = 'u')
        OR
        (bsb.product_id IN ((select * from dbo.StringToTable('32,33,34,36,37,38,40,41,42',','))) AND bsb.product_type = 'o')
        )
```

UPDATE:

Hi, I need another solution here. I implemented John's parser function and the performance of my query dropped from 3 sec to 30 sec. Considering that the query above in my post is a part of multiple UNION, which is a part of common table expression query, my report runs from before 10 to 15 min and now, the page does not complete at all. The report is an aggregate of large record sets and pulls a lot of aggregate values.

Any input greatly appreciated.

Corrections to arguments should look like below:

```
AND 
    (
      (bsb.product_id IN (31,34,37) AND  bsb.product_type = 's')
    OR
      (bsb.product_id IN (20,22,24) AND  bsb.product_type = 't')
    OR
      (bsb.product_id IN (17,18,19,20,21) AND  bsb.product_type = 'u')
    OR
    (bsb.product_id IN (32,33,34,36,37,38,40,41,42) AND bsb.product_type = 'o')
    )
```

> UPDATE 2

@John
Thank you for the reply. New version is a bit better but its not there.
I updated full query with updated parser and plugged in CTE. Run time has fallen from 30 sec to 20 sec. 
I plugged in different versions in WHERE clause to compare with the same set of arguments (quite large list)

1. This one I have used and, it is fastest, runs 2 sec but, it not reliable because of duplicates in id's and types. For example there can be id=34 and type='s' and type='t'. Therefore, I can not use it.

`AND bsb.product_id IN ((select * from      dbo.fnStringToTable('1321,1596,1773,1595,1320,799,1775...',','))) AND  bsb.product_type IN ('t','s','o','u')`

2. This one with CTE by John (post below) runs 20 sec.

   ```
   AND bsb.product_id IN (Select benefitID from cteKey) 
   AND bsb.product_type IN   (Select benefitType from cteType)
   ```
3. This one runs 15 sec.

   ```
   AND (
    bab.product_id = 23 AND bab.product_type = 'o'
    OR 
    bab.product_id = 3 AND bab.product_type = 's'
    OR 
    bab.product_id = 1 AND bab.product_type = 't'
    OR 
    bab.product_id = 7 AND bab.product_type = 'u'
    OR 
    bab.product_id = 18 AND bab.product_type = 's'
    OR 
    bab.product_id = 1 AND bab.product_type = 's'
    .....)
   ```
4. This one runs 4 sec and I think is ideal under circumstances

   ```
   AND (
   bab.product_id IN (583, 585, 584, 595, 597, 596, 720, 722, 721, 723)
   AND bab.product_type = 'o'

   OR bab.product_id IN (718, 717, 727, 726, 894, 893, 896, 895, 898, 897, 900, 899) AND bab.product_type = 's'  

   OR bab.product_id IN (470, 469, 480, 479, 619, 618, 621, 620, 623, 622, 625, 624) AND bab.product_type = 't'  

   OR  bab.product_id IN (388, 392, 446, 447, 450,     451, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458) AND bab.product_type = 'u'
   )
   ```

Basically, I think I need to separate my arguments by type ('1_s, 22_o, 1_u, 35_t, 28_s, 17_o, 1_t') into a list for each type and build it as in #4.

Comment: Unclear what your asking, how are they passed? As a string? what is the relationship between them and the hardcoded CSV values in your query?  How do you split them to char+int? - You should consider alternative approaches (a table-valued-parameter) rather then the many StringToTable() calls which will perform terribly.

Comment: Why not pass in a table parameter? Seems much easier to handle for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Updated:**  Notice the final JOIN and the removal of the WHERE.  This
>   should do what #4 is doing.

The first cte will parse your string (note updated parser)

The second and third cte generate unique keys which are then applied in you where, which may be migrated into the tblStatementProduct JOIN.

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = '34_o,31_s,32_o,20_t,18_u,17_u,33_o,38_o,34_s,36_o,22_t,20_u,19_u,37_o,42_o,37_s,40_o,24_t,22_u,21_u,41_o'

;with cteParse as (
        Select B.*
         From (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,',')) A
         Cross Apply (
               Select Type     =max(case when RetSeq=2 then RetVal else '' end)
                     ,KeyValue =max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal else '' end)
                From (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.RetVal,'_')) C
         ) B ) 
SELECT COUNT(bs.product_id) as num_of_products
     , jb.join_id
     , jb.join_name
     , jb.join_name_fr
     , SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.ee_premium,0),2) + Round(ISNULL(ebs.employer_premium,0),2)) AS premium
     , SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.ee_premium,0),2)) AS ee_premium
     , SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.er_premium,0),2)) AS er_premium
     , SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.ee_tax_prov,0),2) + Round(ISNULL(ebs.er_tax_prov,0),2)) AS sales_tax
     , SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.ee_tax_fed,0),2) + Round(ISNULL(ebs.er_tax_fed,0),2)) AS fed_tax
     , SUM(Round(ISNULL(ebs.ee_tax_hst,0),2) + Round(ISNULL(ebs.er_tax_hst,0),2)) AS hst_tax
     , jb.order_id
     , CASE WHEN bsb.product_type in ('t','u','o') THEN SUM(volume)  ELSE 0 END AS volume_billed
     , CASE WHEN bsb.product_type = 's' THEN ebs.product_category ELSE '' END
 FROM BillStatement ebs
 INNER JOIN tblEmpInfo bei ON bei.billstatementvalue_id = ebs.billstatementvalue_id
 INNER JOIN tblStatementProduct bsb ON bsb.statementproduct_id = ebs.statementproduct_id
 INNER JOIN tblStatement bs ON bs.statement_id = bsb.statement_id
 INNER JOIN JoinedPlanPoducts jb ON jb.product_id = bsb.product_id AND jb.product_type = bsb.product_type
 INNER JOIN cteParse ps on (bsb.product_id = ps.KeyValue and bsb.product_type = ps.Type
 GROUP BY jb.join_id, jb.join_name, jb.join_name_fr, jb.order_id, bsb.product_type, ebs.product_category
```

**Updated** UDF which is a Single Statement TVF

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Comment: Thank you John. Your parser works better this time, I ran some tests and posted findings in my original post UPDATE 2, Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user1706426 I flippled Product and Type.  Corrected

Comment: @user1706426 the parse will add 30ms to the query.  No reason why we can't the same results as #4

Comment: @John...did tests, came back with 15 sec. I was thinking may be to create a function that would give a table output type: column_id : column_type with output '1,22,33,54' : 's'....'21,32,11..' : 't'... Can this be used as a condition or, that can be used only in dynamic query?

Comment: @user1706426 May be the only way to go to get that 4 seconds.  Now, I always say there is no shame in TEMP tables.   Consider dropping the results of cteParse into #cteParse and join change the final join to #cteParse.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a Parser and a cross apply, you could resolve this once and filter on type.

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = '34_o,31_s,32_o,20_t,18_u,17_u,33_o,38_o,34_s,36_o,22_t,20_u,19_u,37_o,42_o,37_s,40_o,24_t,22_u,21_u,41_o'

Select B.*
 From (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,',')) A
 Cross Apply (
       Select Type     =max(case when Key_PS=2 then Key_Value else '' end)
             ,KeyValue =max(case when Key_PS=1 then Key_Value else '' end)
        From (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Key_Value,'_')) C
 ) B
```

Returns

```
Type    KeyValue
o       34
s       31
o       32
t       20
u       18
u       17
o       33
o       38
...
u       22
u       21
o       41
```

My Parser if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

Comment: Thank you, John. Works great

Comment: @user1706426 Happy to help.  I get a tremendous amount of mileage from the parser.

Comment: Hi, I need another solution here. I implemented John's function and the performance of the query dropped from 3 sec to 30 sec. Considering that the query above in my post is a part of multiple UNION, which is a part of common table expression query, my report runs from before 10 min and now, the page does not complete at all. Any input greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user1706426 Not being defensive here, but that parser performs very well.  On a random sample of 5000 records my 8K parser took an average of 77.8ms while the parser listed above (less intimidating) took an average 81..66ms.  Perhaps a JOIN rather than an IN () will yield better results

Comment: I used it in JOIN and tried CROSS APPLY. Same result. It works well  resulting in correct set of values but, performance really went down. I have not tried using in IN though as I need to match row by row in pair of product_id and product_type.